# Can we automate testing for in-app purchases in iOS using XCTest ? If yes, then how?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ui-automation, xctest, xcuitest

I want to automate the process of making an in-app purchase in an iOS native app using XCTest. Is it possible using XCTest? or any other way?

Thanks for help in advance. :)